# Kill a python process when busy in a loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kill, terminate, sigint

I'm running a script on my Raspberry. Sometimes happens that the program freezes, so I've to close the terminal and re-run the .py

So I wanted to "multiprocess" this program. I made two function, the first one does the work, the second one has the job to check the time, and kill the process of the first function in the case the condition is true.

However I tried to do like so:

```
def AntiFreeze():
    print("AntiFreeze partito\n")

    global stop
    global endtime
    global freq

    proc_SPN = multiprocessing.Process(target=SPN(), args=())
    proc_SPN.start()

    time.sleep(2)

    proc_SPN.terminate()
    proc_SPN.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc_AF = multiprocessing.Process(target=AntiFreeze(), args=())
    proc_AF.start()
```

The main function start the "AntiFreeze" function on a process, this one create another process to run the function that will do the Job I want.

**THE PROBLEM (I think):**
The function "SPN()" (that is the one that does the job) is busy in a very long while loop that calls function in another .py file.
So when I use `proc_SPN.terminate()` or `proc_SPN.kill()` nothing happens... why?

There is another way to force a process to kill? maybe I've to do two different programs?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Can you figure out why the program freezes? This might be more easy to solve than adding a layer of complexity by multiprocessing.

Comment: @Dschoni .. actually I don't know, I tried to understand but it is more complicated than it looks.

i had to add a fan over the raspberry to prevent it from overheating. after I added the fan, this problem decreased a lot. but sometimes still happends

Comment: One more thing, you should leave out the brackets in the target argument. 
`proc_SPN = multiprocessin.Process(target=SPN)`

Comment: Change `target=AntiFreeze()` to `target=AntiFreeze` — otherwise you're calling the target in the call that creates the `Process` object. Same issue with the `target=SPN()`.

Comment: I'm thinking, for your special problem, multiprocessing might make things actually worse as you're trying to utilise more CPU power and if overheating is an issue might lead to more failures. You can try making the initial program more efficient (e.g. using less CPU) or trying to artificially slow it down to save on CPU usage and therefore limit excess heat. Can you show code of the `SPN` function?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function at process creation, so most likely the process is never correctly spawned. Your code should be changed into:

```
def AntiFreeze():
    print("AntiFreeze partito\n")

    global stop
    global endtime
    global freq

    proc_SPN = multiprocessing.Process(target=SPN, args=())
    proc_SPN.start()

    time.sleep(2)

    proc_SPN.terminate()
    proc_SPN.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc_AF = multiprocessing.Process(target=AntiFreeze, args=())
    proc_AF.start()
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't use globals (unless strictly necessarry). You could pass the needed arguments to the `AntiFreeze` function instead.